# Regular expression for ALL CAPS at the beginning of a text block in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm having difficulty in putting together a regex pattern that separates out all caps words in the beginning of a paragraph with the rest of the paragraph.

```
    text_example = 
      """HERE IS SOME TEXT, AND HERE IS SOME MORE; AND ANOTHER START. There is a lot of text 
      that I am also interested in extracting and that will have a variety of Information, 
      symbols @#$^*&^ and even amounts such as $4,123,156 to be included as well."""
```

Suppose I have the above text. I want to capture `HERE IS SOME TEXT, AND HERE IS SOME MORE; AND ANOTHER START.` - a pattern of all caps words and punctuation at the start of a passage - and the remaining `There is a lot of text that I am also interested in...` - that is text with symbols, numbers, and some capital letters at the start of new sentences or for names etc.

I have the following pattern I've been working on and it isn't quite right

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z]+\s?[A-Z]+[^a-z0-9])(.*)")
passage_start = re.search(pattern, text).group(1)
passage_remaining = re.search(pattern, text).group(2)

print(passage_start)
print()
print(passage_remaining)
```

When running this, I get:

```
HERE IS

SOME TEXT, AND HERE IS SOME MORE; AND ANOTHER START. There is a lot of text that I 
am also interested in extracting and that will have a variety of Information, symbols 
@#$^*&^ and even amounts such as $4,123,156 to be included as well.
```

Would appreciate some help! Thanks

Comment: Something like `(^[^a-z]*(?![a-z]))(.*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^([^a-z]+)\b(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYRPpB/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `([^a-z]+)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, as many as possible.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/79l7CZ):

```py
import re
rx = r"^([^a-z]+)\b(.*)"
text = "HERE IS SOME TEXT, AND HERE IS SOME MORE; AND ANOTHER START. There is a lot of text that I am also interested in extracting and that will have a variety of Information, symbols @#$^*&^ and even amounts such as $4,123,156 to be included as well."
m = re.search(rx, text, re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # HERE IS SOME TEXT, AND HERE IS SOME MORE; AND ANOTHER START. 
    print(m.group(2)) # There is a lot of text that I am also interested in extracting and that will have a variety of Information, symbols @#$^*&^ and even amounts such as $4,123,156 to be included as well.
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked well. I also appreciated the explanation and added details

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that there will be a space between the caps and non caps part, you could use `^([A-Z\.,; ]*) (.*)` with the `re.DOTALL` flag set.

If the space between the parts CANT be guaranteed, you can use `^([A-Z\.,; ]*) ?(.*)` (again with the `re.DOTALL` flag), but you need to then move the last character of the first group to the second group.